# Almost 1k of messages from one Azure IoT Edge device after 6 hours?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I'm evaluating Azure IoT Hub and their IoT Edge device. Since I'm using free tier including 6k of messages I thought this was no issue but after 6 hours and only one Edge device we are have already used 1k of daily message quota.

Does anyone know how this works? I have not sent any payload c2d or d2c

The log is full of this kind of messages. Does the daemon poll the hub and every poll is one message?

Worth mentioning is that I have 4 custom modules that are NOT connected to the Hub, they are more or less just docker containers running on their own but managed by IoT Hub.

```
Oct 25 14:08:22 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:22Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:22 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:22Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:27 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:27Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:27 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:27Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:32 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:32Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:32 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:32Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:37 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:37Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:37 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:37Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:42 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:42Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:42 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:42Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:47 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:47Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:47 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:47Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:52 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:52Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:52 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:52Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Oct 25 14:08:57 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:57Z [INFO] - <-- GET /modules?api-version=2022-08-03 {"accept": "application/json", "host": "mgmt.sock:80", "connection": "close"}
Oct 25 14:08:57 iot-edge-test aziot-edged[3465]: 2022-10-25T14:08:57Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
```

[image]

Any idea of the high message count?

Thanks,
Johan

Comment: Take a look at the built in EventHub endpoint, it should show you what telemetry was sent to the hub.

Comment: +1 monitoring messages via EventHub compatible endpoint in IoT Hub is required to troubleshoot, you can use Azure IoT Hub explorer tool   https://github.com/azure/iothub-explorer  or  CLI  "az iot hub monitor-events -n {iothub_name} -d {device_id} --cg {consumer_group_name}"   Also note the edgeAgent does get the deployment manifest via its twin and reports back which gets counted, but the rate and count seems to be high here.

Comment: Thanks! I have been monitoring EventHub but it's nothing there, it's very quiet.

I added a screen shot of current metrics for context to the original post